this._user.next(value); is not propagating to the GUI in which cases?
I am going off a template and I have the following UserService

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    private _baseClient = inject(BaseClient);
    private _singleModel = inject(SingleModel);
    private _user: ReplaySubject<UserData> = new ReplaySubject<UserData>(1);
    private _lastUser?: UserData;

    /**
     * Setter & getter for user
     *
     * @param value
     */
    setUser(value: UserData) {
        // Store the value
        this._user.next(value);
        this._lastUser = value;
    }

    lastUser() {
        return this._lastUser;
    }

    get user$(): Observable<UserData> {
        return this._user.asObservable();
    }
...
}

I have a resolver that calls fetchUserData and calls setUser above which triggers the GUI elements to update when data is received including the photoUrl which is the field I am working on.
In another case, I have a dialogue and a button 'Upload' and the dialogue goes away and when upload is done, I clond that _lastUser data only modifying the photoUrl but none of the images get live updates.  I am logging the UserData just before calling setUser as well and the url is correct(ie. the new one).
In what cases do I need to watch out for with Observables.  Why is updating the Observable with this._user.next(value) not updating the GUI elements.  They update only sometimes?
Here is one of the image gui elements
<img
  class="h-full w-full rounded-full"
  [src]="user.avatar"
  alt="User avatar"
/>

Is there some component context I need to get into to make this work?  I was hoping anyone can just update the obsevable but that is not working in this one case.
I also tried adding     this.cdr.detectChanges(); which did not fix the issue..
    this._userService.user$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((user: UserData) => {
            this.user = user;
            this._cdr.detectChanges();
        });


How exactly are you subscribing to the user$ Observable in your component?

The last snipped of code in my post is how I am subscribed.  @JSONDerulo however, I got it working.  strict:true was not on and I was changing wrong field in UserData AND on top of that, I had to add what another method had _cdr.markForCheck() for some reason too.
